# Hide Menu section in Sharepoint with CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to hide a section from the Menu Ribbon in SharePoint 2013.
I used FireBug to see find out the relevant ID and CLASS

[image]
this is the css related to the whole section marked in red

```
<li id="Ribbon.Library.CustomViews" class="ms-cui-group" unselectable="on">
<span class="ms-cui-groupContainer" unselectable="on">
<span class="ms-cui-groupBody" unselectable="on">
<span id="Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium" class="ms-cui-layout" unselectable="on">
<span id="Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium-0" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">
<span id="Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium-1" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">
<span id="Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium-2" class="ms-cui-section" unselectable="on">
</span>
</span>
<span class="ms-cui-groupTitle" unselectable="on">Manage Views</span>
</span>
<span class="ms-cui-groupSeparator" unselectable="on"></span>
</li>
```

I have tried the following :

```
<style type="text/css">
#Ribbon.Library.CustomViews .ms-cui-group .ms-cui-groupContainer .ms-cui-groupBody  { display:none; visibility: hidden;  }
#Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium .ms-cui-layout .ms-cui-section .Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium-0 .Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium-1 .Ribbon.Library.CustomViews-LargeMedium-2 .ms-cui-groupTitle  { display:none; visibility: hidden; }
</style>
```

Unfortunately is not working :(

**What is my aim ?**

Well, I got a custom list containing 10 files which is accessible by 2 groups. However, only one group can see the full content whereas the other group should see only certain files.

Therefore, I created 2 different Views:  UserView | ManagerView

**What is the problem with that?**

the users can still navigate to ManagerView and see the full content. That is the reason why I want to disable the option of selecting Current View: or even to modify it or create new view.

Of course, the Users got READ only but still are able to select both views, which is not ideal. Otherwise I am left with creating 2 separate custom lists!

Any advise would be grateful.

*PS: Trying to hide it via CSS (using Script Editor in SP2013) as anything else is too advanced for myself e.g. editing the master page etc.*

**UPDATE**

The code HarryB provided did the trick: 
[image]

*However, anyone who is a bit curious still can access the ManagerView via the URL, if they know the link to it.*

Comment: Try the css in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css:

```
   <style>
    .ms-cui-tabBody li:nth-child(2) {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: how you managed that :) it worked like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the selectors you were trying to use in CSS has dot(.) in the attribute, you would prepend by a '\'.

Example CSS:

```
li#Ribbon\.List\.CustomViews {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: this had been suggested by other guys (who seem to have removed their comments) but did not get it work. Anyway thanks for your suggestion :)